# Cómo obtener el Precio Total cuando se ingresa la cantidad con JS

Tags: javascript, angular

tengo que obtener el precio total cuando ingreso la cantidad, el precio unitario ya lo estoy obteniendo a través del consumo de un servicio.
La interfaz está así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, debería tener un evento change que cuando ingrese la cantidad en este caso 5 automaticamente me devuelva el Precio Total. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Para el código js estoy utilizando TypeScript y el proyecto lo estoy realizando con angular.
El codigo de la tabla lo tengo así:

```
<ng-template #template>


  <div class="modal-header zoom">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{'extras.registrar_OC' | translate}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>


  <div class="modal-body zoom">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputPassword4" class="col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Codigo
          Producto</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <select class="form-control" #codProducto="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.codProducto"
            name="codProducto" #matnr (change)="onChangeCodigoDescripcionOC(matnr.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let claseProducto of producto" [value]="claseProducto.matnr">{{claseProducto.matnr}}
            </option>
            <!---{{claseProducto.maktx}}-->
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputEmail4"
          class="col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Descripción</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" class="form-control" #descripcion="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.descripcion" name="descripcion" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputEmail4" class=" col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Centro</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <select class="form-control" class="form-control" #centro="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.centro" name="centro">
            <option *ngFor="let claseCentro of centros" [value]="claseCentro.werks">{{claseCentro.werks}} - {{claseCentro.name1}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputEmail4" class=" col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Cantidad</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" class="form-control" #cantidad="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.cantidad" name="cantidad">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputEmail4" class=" col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Precio Unitario</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" class="form-control" #precioUnitario="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.precioUnitario" name="precioUnitario" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputEmail4" class=" col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Precio Total</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" class="form-control" #precioTotal="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.precioTotal" name="precioTotal" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btnPos">
        <button type="button" title="Registrar" class="btn" (click)="onRegistrar($event)">
          <i class="simple-icon-check icon"></i>
          <h3 class="exec">Ejecutar</h3>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, GRACIAS!

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: Hola BetaM, soy nuevo. Cómo hago eso?

Comment: Copialo y pégalo como texto, posterior lo seleccionas y presionas el ícono de `{}` o presionas *ctrl + k* para darle formato, lee aqui [ask]

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya lo actualicé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay mucho código espaguetti aquí, para que tengas control de tu aplicación te recomendaría dejes de usar `ngModel` Y pases a usar [Formularios reactivos](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) eso te dará más control de tu HTML. Ahora con respecto a lo que preguntas, te recomendaría agregar esta instrucción al `input` de Cantidad `(keyup)="calculate()"` para que te quede así

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label style="color:  #004db0;font-size: 15px;" for="inputEmail4" class=" col-md-5 col-form-label mr-0">Cantidad</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" class="form-control" (keyup)="calculate()" #cantidad="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="headerOrdenCompraModal.cantidad" name="cantidad">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ahora en el archivo de lógica ( por lo general lleva un nombre similar a esto **modal-precio.component.ts** ) deberás agregar la función que escribimos en el `keyup`

```
calculate(): void {
  const base     = this.headerOrdenCompraModal;
  const cantidad = Number(base.cantidad );
  const precio   = Number( base.precioUnitario );
  const total    = cantidad * precio;
  base.precioTotal = total;
}
```

Con eso deberías poder obtener el resultado que estás esperando

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto, me funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Si te funcionó, recuerda marcala como correcta, dando clic en el la palomita. Esto sirve para que otros desarrolladores con el mismo problema puedan guiarse.